# An expression was successfully parsed, but extra characters were found after it

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, terraform-provider-azure

I have a "create_vm" module which is creating VM plus storage account, NIC etc.

My requirement is I want to pass IP address list from root module to create_vm module so anyone can restrict in bound connections to VM as per their requirement. Correct me I'm not using correct terminology for modules.

Directory structure looks like this:

```
subscription_1  subscription_2  Modules  README.md  

./subscription_1:

./subscription_2:
main.tf  sqlvm.tf.bak  terraform.tfstate  terraform.tfstate.backup  variables.tf

./Modules:
create_vm

./Modules/create_vm:
main.tf  variable.tf
```

**cat ./Modules/create_vm/main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "tf-nsr-5986" {
...
  source_address_prefixes     = "${var.allowed_source_ips}"
...
}
```

**cat ./Modules/create_vm/variable.tf**

```
variable "allowed_source_ips" {
  description = "List of ips from which inbound connection to VMs is allowed"
  type        = "list"
}
```

Utilizing this in root module
cat ./subscription_2/main.tf

```
module "vm_app" {
...
  allowed_source_ips  = "${var.ip_list}"
...
}
```

cat ./subscription_2/variable.tf

```
variable "ip_list" {
  description = "List of ips from which inbound connection to VMs is allowed"
  type        = "list"
}
```

Now, I am running terraform from my local vm, by passing arguments, exactly the way I would on Azure DevOps pipeline

```
terraform plan -var "resource_group_name=nxt-grp-prd-manage-rgp-au-se" -var "virtual_network_name=virtual_network_1" -var "sql_subnet_name=subnet_1" -var "app_subnet_name=subnet_2" -var "application_nsg=test_nsg" -var "count_vm=2" -var "sql_host_basename=sqlvms" -var "app_host_basename=appvms" -var "storage_account_suffix=sta" -var "virtual_machine_size=Standard_B1ms" -var "virtual_machine_image_publisher=MicrosoftWindowsServer" -var "virtual_machine_image_offer=WindowsServer" -var "virtual_machine_image_sku=2012-R2-Datacenter" -var "virtual_machine_image_version=latest" -var "username=devopsadmin" -var "password=Angular12#$%" -var "ip_list="a.b.c.d","p.q.r.s","x.y.z.l""
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the error message as like below:

```
Error: Invalid number literal

  on <value for var.ip_list> line 1:
  (source code not available)

Failed to recognize the value of this number literal.


Error: Extra characters after expression

  on <value for var.ip_list> line 1:
  (source code not available)

An expression was successfully parsed, but extra characters were found after
it.
```

Has anyone solved this type of challenge before? Not really sure why it is complaining, I'm giving the same way I have given before in create_vm module.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assing a list to the ip_list variable, not a string. You're expecting a list but you're assigning a string (that's technically fine, it gets parsed into a list with single string in it. ) and then a comma, which is the extra character.

Instead you should pass a proper list as a parameter, notice the 'array' / [] (square brackets) notation.

```
 ... -var "ip_list=["a.b.c.d","p.q.r.s","x.y.z.l"] ...
```

---

I'd also strongly encourage you to use a variable file instead. You'll then get some linting/terraform language support. That will allow you to spot mistakes easier before running tf apply in ci/cd.

You would create a file `variables.tfvars`:

```
...
variable "ip_list" {
  description = "List of ips ..."
  default     = ["a.b.c.d","p.q.r.s","x.y.z.l"]
}
...
```

You can then pass the whole file as a paramter to `terraform apply -var-file="./variables.tfvars"`.

Answer (score 1):

Look for type mismatches between your input variable and what you are actually sending in.

This is a generalized error that tends to surface when the type for an input is a map or list and a string was given. I believe it has something to do with the way Terraform tries to convert inputs to what is set in the input variable.

Example:
Given the following in a `variables.tf` in a module named `test`

```
variable "foo" {
  type = map
}
```

If you instantiate your module like this:

```
module "example" {
  source = "./test"
  foo = <<-EOT
  bar
  EOT
}
```

This errors will surface.

In most cases Terraform tries to prevent this, but some things slip through (such as heredoc syntax).